# What are the "categories" of info header bars?

Tags: discussion

Out of curiosity, and because I close and forget about them, which categories can the info bars fall under? Right now I have three:

- You've earned a badge
- Your associated account +100 rep
- Earned a privilege

How many more of these exist?

In the comments these were listed:

- Moderator Elections (Mysticial)
- Migration (Manishearth)
- Pending Bounties (Manishearth)
- Moderator messages and suspensions—you'll get them if you're the recipient or you're a mod on the site and another mod sent one. (waiwai933)

I think some were temporary and there are alerts in a box below the logo like downtime alerts (animuson)

Comment: This is rather open-ended, and is worded in such a way that it's a challenge to see how many orange bars can be stacked up before people click "x" to dismiss them.  Your answer is unknown/defined by system resources.

Comment: Downtime alerts normally appear in a different box down below the logo and links.

Comment: I've had 3 before: Badge, Privilege, and Moderator Election banner.

Comment: @casperOne Gotcha, I was thinking it's a finite list but didn't know that system resources affected it.

Comment: @MiaDiLorenzo Well, more likely system resources on *your* end.  If you have a gazillion bars not dismissed, then well, that's your prerogative, and limited to *your* very specific set of resources available to you in the browser process.

Comment: I know how to make more stack up. Check out the `StackExchange.notify` object in your browser JS console. One of the methods (can't remember which, on mobile) adds a bar when you provide the HTML contents as a parameter. It's most pribably infinite.

Comment: If you want, I can complete your 'challenge' in a day. Just let me get back to a desktop browser. :)

Comment: @Manishearth  YES! It's `StackExchange.notify.show("message")` Fantastic, Manishearth!

Comment: Well, the purpose of the question was to identify the types of messages (like badge, rep, moderator), but I did phrase it like a game.

Comment: @Mia IIRC, that's not the one, it's the one with a longer name. This one works, but the dismiss buttons don't on these.

Comment: @Manishearth Phew, they go away with a refresh. I wonder what it is, the only other promising notify function was showMessages and it's not the right one either.

Comment: Badges, , migration, pending bounties.. That's it I think. Regarding the notify object, I'll check it out tomorrow. Of course they go away with a refresh, the sticky ones are server side. I can userscript a few stickies for you though ;)

Comment: If you edit your question to  make it less challenge-y, I'll vote to reopen for you.

Comment: Well, it's still a "List" question which I should've seen as not a good type of question. Thanks for the offer but I think it'll get closed again. Anyway, the manual insertion of header bars was good fun.

Comment: @Mia not really a list, since the answer set is small. Its something the devs would know, I guess. Or long time users. Though you might be right thay it may get reclosed. Anyway, you still need a few reopenvotes.

Comment: @Manishearth Thanks again for the vote. Also, someone upvoted it :D

Comment: @mia that's me. And reopen vote is not the same as a normal vote.

Comment: @Manishearth I was imagining it was you :) I appreciate not one, but two of your votes.

Comment: Adding to the list: Moderator messages and suspensions—you'll get them if you're the recipient or you're a mod on the site and another mod sent one.

Comment: @mia there, reopened by me, another guy, and the same mod who closed it :p

Comment: @Manishearth Wonderful, thanks to your hard work! I wish there was a "Your question has been reopened" bar :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(CW since no one may know the full thing)

Please try adding the text for each message if you recall it.

### Normal stuff

- Badges [*You've earned the "Civic Duty" badge. See your profile.*]
- Privileges [You have gained the privilege-- ]
- Pending bounty(on all sites)
- Auto awarded bounty (I think)
- Your associated account ... awards +100 rep

### Due to mod magic

- Migrated question (but not answer)
- Suspended account
- Mod message sent to you

### Mod stuff

- All mod messages
- All suspensions
- Esoteric stuff I'm not meant to know.